# Extracting information from the database by choosing the most suitable one out of 3 conditions with PHP

Tags: mysql

I searched a lot on the internet about the subject I was going to ask, but unfortunately I could not find a useful result.

I have table named "POST"

```
postID | postDesc | postStatus  | userID
_______________________________________
1      | Lorem... | public      | 1
2      | Ipsum... | private     | 1
3      | Dolor... | university  | 1
```

I have another table named "Follow". In this table, I record who follows whom. For example:

```
followID | follow1 | follow2
____________________________
1        | 1       | 2
2        | 3       | 1
```

In my table named "Follow", the follower's id is in the follow1 column and the id of the followed person is in follow2. For you to understand this better, my table named "user" is as follows:

```
userID | userName | universityID
________________________________
1      | John     | 1
2      | Crowell  | 3
3      | Risav    | 1
```

What I'm trying to do is if the data in the post table is public then anyone will be able to see it. If it is private, only followers will be able to see it. If it is a university, people with the same university ID will be able to see it.
For example, the user with id 1 wrote all the information in my "post" table. Now, if the user with 2 id numbers can view these posts, they will only be able to see the public post. Number 3 will be able to see both private posts and university posts. Because user number 3 follows user number 1 and also they both have the same university id.

I hope I explained in detail.

Code I wrote myself

```
SELECT * FROM post
INNER JOIN user ON post.userID=user.userID 
WHERE post.postStatus='public' and post.postStatus='follower' 
and EXISTS (SELECT * FROM follow where follow.follow2=user.userID and follow.follow1='some user id')"
```

Comment: side note, choosing meaningful names is helpful both to you and others; "follow1" and "follow2" doesn't convey any meaning about the data, why not use something like "following_Id" and "followed_Id"...?

Comment: I usually try to put the column names with the same name as the table name. I named them follow1 and follow2 so that the column names are not too long. Actually what you said is true.

Comment: If not having too long names are important then just call them "1" and "2" - you don't need "follow" as it's already determined by the table name.

Comment: Why there is php in tis question if your goal is SQL? Never mix isselevant matters

Comment: Please write if you can help me find the answer. You're wasting your time saying the tag name is wrong. Even if the tag name is wrong, I still believe it is an issue that concerns software developers working in PHP.